# Scrolling page is laggy

Tags: html, optimization, lag

The page that I created has a problem when scrolling up and down...Is it because there is too much on it? What's the solution?
my page: http://www.orhsfoundation.com/index12.html
Sorry for being generic, the problem is pretty much "overall".. The problem occurs mainly on chrome and my iPhone...maybe a little on Firefox but not really noticeable.
Iv'e tried to reduce image size and saw no difference.
the problem doesn't happen on other pages that use the same Dreamweaver template so it could be the banner in the middle.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clicking on a random link to an unknown site. Can you provide details, or replicate the problem using http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sorry I was being generic, the problem is pretty much "overall" and I didn't think code will help much.. The problem occurs mainly on chrome and my iPhone...maybe a little on Firefox but not really noticeable.

Comment: to start i've seen that you're calling all your jquery libraries twice and that it's not helping.
eg. you first call them as `/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js` and straight after as `/Assets/JS/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`. start by avoid double call.

Comment: @user1533928: Suggest editing your original question to include the information you added as a comment, as well as any techniques you've tried so far to resolve the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/); it may give you some useful performance-related advice.